# Set Bootstrap Carousel Items to Element With Greatest Height

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am dynamically loading content with text of varying length into a Bootstrap Carousel component.  In order to prevent the parent container from jumping around in height with the loading of each carousel item, I'd like to identify the max height of all the items and set the height to the largest one.  That way I can handle the layout with padding, etc. without the other flex items on the page moving around.

```
 <div id="carouselExampleSlidesOnly" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
  <div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="carousel-item active">
        <img src="..." class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <img src="..." class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <img src="..." class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        //set all carousel items to the highest container
        var containers = document.getElementsByClassName('carousel-item');
        var max_height = 0;

        //find highest container
        for (var i = 0; i < containers.length; i++) {
            var container_height = containers[i].offsetHeight;
            if (container_height > max_height) {
                max_height = container_height;               
            }
        }

        //set container heights
        for (var i = 0; i < containers.length; i++) {
            containers[i].offsetHeight = max_height;
        }
    });
</script>
```

This does not work, as the only container with a hight > 0 is the one being displayed.  Is there a way to simulate the height of these containers, without actually displaying them?

Answer (score 0):

This is similar solution to your issue. I think you can get an idea from this.

```
$(".goodness-left-item").each(function( no1 ) 

    var index1 = $(this).index();
    var height1 = $(this).height();

    $(".goodness-right-item").each(function( no2 ) {
        var index2 = $(this).index();
        if(index1 == index2){
            var height2 = $(this).height();
            if(height1 < height2){
                $(".goodness-left-item").eq(index1).css("min-height",height2);
            }
            else{
                $(this).css("min-height",height1);         
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm not following here.  Wouldn't this essentially be doing the same thing as what I've attempted?  The output of this would be they all match the element that's actually being displayed.